# Random Number Generation with constraints in any programming language

Tags: python, matlab, math, random

I want to generate 150 random numbers with values as positive integers `(1,2,3,4,5.....)` such that sum of all random numbers is 270 and

```
Prob[1] = 0.405
Prob[2] = 0.345
Prob[3] = 0.125
Prob[4] = 0.092
Prob[>=5] = 0.033
```

Basically, sum of all random numbers is fixed, probability is fixed and random number should take values greater than 0.

Does anyone know how can I generate it in python/MATLAB/C or any other programming language.

Comment: You have contradicting requirements. If 150 numbers has a fixed sum, at least one of them is not independently random. You may draw 149 according to your distribution, and calculate the last one from the current and target sums. Would it work?

Comment: yes, you are right. It would be fine that way....atleast one of them would not be random.

Comment: How flexible are those probabilities? For example 0.405*150 = 60.75 so must there be 61 ones in the result? Worse still 0.405*150*1 + 0.345*150*2 + 0.125*150*3 + 0.092*150*4 = 275.7 which is greater than the maximum sum of 270...

Comment: Yes, I know, thats what constraint makes the problem difficult. Its kind of optimization problem where one constraint is affecting the other constraint. I have thought the same as you but I think, some error will always be there in probability if sum is to be met.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the table such that it has cumulative sums of probabilities:

```
[ 0.405, 0.750, 0.875, 0.967, 1.0 ]
```

Draw a uniform random from (0.0, 1.0). Search the table for the smallest entry greater than the number drawn; the index is your value. Add to total. Repeat 149 times.

Subtract total from 270 to get the last one.

Comment: While this solution would work, provided the constraints are, in fact, sensible, it would never produce a solution which contained a number greater than five, which is clearly allowed in the question.

Comment: I have done this, and I keep counting the sum in each iteration while assigning a random number {1,2,3,4,5,....} based on the method you told. The sum crosses 270 sometimes at 143 position, sometimes at 141 position. So, now there is nothing left to be allotted, it means I need to subtract something from earlier values to allot atleast 1 to left of the 7 or 9 positions.

Comment: Come to think of it, the last number could be greater than five - but only the last number. However, the bigger problem is that 150 numbers with the probability distribution specified in the question add up to more than 270...

Comment: The numbers (when distributed according to given distribution) add up to 270 till some position before 150 . After that, some thing needs to be done!!! I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: @user3388706 It is fairly unlikely that they will sum to 270. You can run multiple simulations and keep the one that adds up to 270. Would that be acceptable? In the case that it does add up, the sampled probability distribution will be fairly different from the desired.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to add up to 270, it might be necessary to repeatedly generate sets of 150 samples, taken from the specified distribution, until the samples add up to 270.  However, in this case, the distribution of values will not be very close to the desired distribution.

In MATLAB, the easiest way to do it is with `randsample`, part of the Signal Processing Toolbox. For example,

```
randsample(1:5, 150, true, [0.405 0.345 0.125 0.092 0.033])
```

Run it until the output sums to 270:

```
rsum = 0;
while rsum~=270,
    rs = randsample(1:5, 150, true, [0.405 0.345 0.125 0.092 0.033]);
    rsum = sum(rs);
end
```

For values >5, maybe you can replace the samples ==5 with a new number taken from a uniform distribution on [5,Inf), or maybe up to `intmax`:

```
fives = rs==5;
rs(fives) = randi(intmax-5+1,nnz(fives)+100,1)+5-1
```

*If you don't have* `randsample`, you can make the samples as follows,

```
N = 150;
vals = 1:5;
p = [0.405 0.345 0.125 0.092 0.033];

cdf = [0 cumsum(p(:).'/sum(p))]; cdf(end)=1;
[~, isamps] = histc(rand(N,1),cdf);
rs = vals(isamps);
```